# Iomega Home Media Network Hard Drive: Filesystem on the disk?

Tags: filesystems, data-recovery

I've got to deal with a malfunctioning "Iomega Home Media Network Hard Drive", and I was wondering if anybody knew what file system format does Iomega use on the disk?

I've been trying to find the answer online, but i've got nowhere, and checking an obviously malfucntioning unit is not going to give me any assurance.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone gets to this question:

I got it solved:

I mounted the drive in a different PC, using Knoppix.

The Data partition (996 MB) is XFS, and it didn't mount properly, but the mount messages suggested using some new "xfs_*" command that validated the config - it said I might lose data, etc but it run very quickly and all the data was there.

Once I could mount it, I copied it somewhere else and am looking for a 2 drive NAS ATM :))

Answer (score 2):

It uses a linux file structure.  I plugged it into my Windows and it did not see the drive so I then mounted on linux and I saw it.

Comment: Hi, DudeJB!

That's extremely good news! Could you tell me as what FS Linux "sees" it?

Doing a "mount -l"  and/or "mount -v" should give you this information, and it'd be extremely helpful!!